# возвращает пустую страницу после формы отправки в php

Tags: php

Почему пустая страница после того как я ввел данные в форме, никаких ошибок и прочего не показывается

index.html

```
 <form action="order.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text"  name="name"  id="name" placeholder="Name"     required class="contact name">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"    required class="contact email">
    <input type="text"  name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title"     required class="contact title">
     <div class="col-md-12">
     <textarea  name="feedback"   placeholder="Your Feedback" class="feedback"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="send">Send Message</button>
    </form>
```

order.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "dadadaya@.com";
    $email_subject = "vasyaPu@gmail.com";

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['title']) ||
        !isset($_POST['feedback'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email= $_POST['email']; 
    $title = $_POST['title']; 
    $feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";


   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  } 

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$title)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Title you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($feedback) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Title: ".clean_string($title)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Feedback: ".clean_string($feedback)."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

}

?>
```

Comment: `include('order.php');` в форме `action="/"` или возвращайте клиента после успешного выполнения на нужную страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST)){

    тут автор отправляет письмо

    $url = 'URL страницы';
    header("Location: ".$url."");
    exit;
}else{
    ?>
    HTML страница
    <?php
}
?>
```

1. после выполнения перенаправляем на URL страницы
2. переменную об отправке/ошибке можно передать через сессию на пример

В примере который выше написан - если отправка все же пойдет, и человек на странице нажмет F5, данные из $_POST будут еще раз отправляеться

Answer (score 1):

Потому что при отправке формы, вы переходите на страницу order.php(в форме в action у вас указано), а эта страница никак визуально не оформлена.